# Virtual-Key Codes for special characters

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard-events

I am trying to get the Virtual-Key Code for another characters out of regular [virtual-key codes list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx), like '<', but I cant find it, it's an ASCII character and I can't find it.

Comment: To get a more meaningful answer: why do you want to find the code? What do you need it for, and how are you intending to use it?

Comment: it is a character, not a virtual key code.  Exactly what keys need to be pressed depends on the thread's active keyboard layout.  Tends to be the same as the default keyboard layout but users do switch with the language bar.  VkKeyScanEx() might help.

Comment: Thank you Hans Passant, VkKeyScanEx('<', GetKeyboardLayout(0)) did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Hans Passant

> VkKeyScanEx() might help.

For example, the Virtual-Key Code equivalent to '<' can be found with:

`VkKeyScanEx('<', GetKeyboardLayout(0))`

Answer (score 2):

“ASCII” is a *character encoding*.<sup>1</sup> This has very little to do with key codes. For example, “A” and “a” have distinct ASCII values but they are represented by the same key on the keyboard (plus a modifier key — <kbd>shift</kbd>).

That’s the reason why you don’t find <kbd><</kbd> in the list — it’s not a key on the (virtual) keyboard represented by these key codes. It depends on the currently active keyboard mapping how this character is represented by by a keycode.

---

<sup>1</sup> And, I might add, not a very relevant one in this day and age. Better forget about ASCII, it’s mostly misused.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I know ASCII and key codes are different things but it's just a sample for missing important characters in the Virtual-Key Code list for US standard keyboard. I know it depends of keyboard mapping, but, in that case, how can I find it?.